# Changing file on a mysql update

Tags: php, mysql

Sorry if the title sounds a bit vague.

Stackoverflow posting newbie here.

I have an address book that I am building and have run into a bit of a problem.

I want to be able to update the record and if no image is set in the update form, to keep the image already noted in the record. If the image field is populated, then update the record with that image and move it to the target location.

This is the if statement I have for it:

```
if (empty($photo))
{
$photo = $row['photo'];
}
else
{           
$phmsg = "Photo $photo has been deleted and replaced";
unlink("".IMAGES."/$photo");
$afn = date('dmYHis');
$name_of_file = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$photo=$afn.$name_of_file;
$target = "".FILE_UPLOAD."/"; 
$target = $target . basename($photo);
}
```

This is the error I get when I try to run the upload:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\cab\update.php on line 165
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpB232.tmp' to '' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cab\update.php on line 165
>
> File was not uploaded. Please try a manual upload.

The only other way around it that I can see is to have a seperate file for updating and not updating the picture.

Any help would be most welcome and very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check the $_FILES array is populated before trying to use it.

Comment: Hi Dagon, the files array is populated as it should be and shows 0 as the error value. I have checked what is being posted in the firebug console and it is showing that the data is being posted. It won't update though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use [`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) without a valid file as parameter.

Check if you have a valid file uploaded, and only then execute `move_uploaded_file()`

Comment: If I use a file to update the record and change the picture, it will post the value of the photo field in the form and update and move the file without issue. With the if statement I have, it doesn't seem to be getting the value of the photo field into $_POST.

Comment: The uploaded file will be in $_FILES, not $_POST

Comment: Hi ilanco, I use the $_POST so I can put the reference to the picture in the db, but also use $_FILES to move it. The issue is getting the file to be recognised. Seems that it sees that the field name is empty even though I have selected a picture for it

Comment: You will need to post all your relevant code here, there is too much information missing.

Comment: et al

The if statement is as it is in the op.

This is the output from the page

`Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\cab\update.php on line 160`

`Warning: move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\phpF846.tmp' to '' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cab\update.php on line 160`

Comment: Oops

`Array ( [photo] => Array ( [name] => CarLogo2.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\phpF846.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 28759 ) )`

It is not being passed through the if statement for some odd reason

Comment: Thanks guys, I just had to make the $pict = $_FILES and not $_POST.

Thanks aagin. PHP dummy here

Answer (score 0):

try this code please

```
if (empty($photo))
{
$photo = $row['photo'];
}
else
{           
$phmsg = "Photo $photo has been deleted and replaced";
unlink("".IMAGES."//$photo");
$afn = date('dmYHis');
$name_of_file = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$photo=$afn.$name_of_file;
$target = "".FILE_UPLOAD."//"; 
$target = $target . basename($photo);
}
```

Comment: Still the same error. It seems it will not get the value of the posted field for photo :(